# MacOS: Cannot open JAR File

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have been trying to install a pair trader on my Mac and have not been having success. Links/specs provided below.

When I try to install the JAR file, I first get the error that this app is from an unknown developer. When I go to system preferences, unlock, and click "open anyway", I get the following error:

**Java Application Failed**
Check console error for possible messages related to "/Users/USER/Downloads/ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar"

I've tried everything on the internet and just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated -  TIA.

**macOS Big Sur 11.6.8**
**java version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS** - This is from running "java -version" in Terminal.
**Java Version 8 Update 351 (build 1.8.0_351-b10)** - This is from the Java Control Panel.
**Link to what I'm trying to install:** https://github.com/quantverse/ptltrader/releases

When I click "open anyway," I expect the JAR file to open and run. I have also tried to "Command + Click" the file in finder, and when I choose "Open With," the only option is JavaLauncher.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what a "pair trader" is?

Comment: What were the console error messages to which you were referred?

Comment: `java -jar ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar 2>&1 | tee err-out.log` Please post the contents of err-out.log in code tags

Comment: @g00se here is what I get: 


`Error: Unable to access jarfile ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar`


I made sure to run this a couple of times and ensured the file name was correct when I ran this in console.

Comment: Is that jar file definitely in the current directory?

Comment: @g00se I believe it is. The path bar in Finder is `USER>Downloads>ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar`

Comment: So. `cd ~/Downloads;java -jar ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar 2>&1 | tee err-out.log`

Comment: @g00se Of course, my apologies. The error is quite long so I will split it into two comments. `***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions. Use vmarg -XstartOnFirstThread
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4889)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4804)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4775)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1100)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:851)`

Comment: `at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:835)
 at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:130)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:734)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:725)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1434)
 at com.pairtradinglab.ptltrader.Application.main(Application.java:310)
(base) sahil@Sahils-MacBook-Pro-4 Downloads % `

Comment: Hmm. Take them at their word and try `java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar 2>&1 | tee err-out.log`

Comment: @g00se It worked! Thank you so much. Is there anything I need to do to mark this as the answer/improve your rating?

Comment: I'm not sure ;) But I'll post it as the answer for you to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar ptltrader-1.6.0-macosx.jar 2>&1 | tee err-out.log
```

(since your error message seems to indicate a gui threading issue)